# what roses can be planted in a pot

Tags: containers, planting, roses

I'm looking to put some yellow roses in a 2' long planter, and my local garden center doesn't have any yellow roses. Perhaps they are out of season? And I see there are a bunch of different kinds of roses (climbing and bush). I'm wondering what sort of roses would be suitable for planting in a pot, and any recomendations about where to acquire them (website?)

Comment: When you say two feet long, I assume you mean the length of the container, but what is the depth from top to bottom?

Comment: @b.nota oh yea, you're right - but can the OP really mean 2 inches long?surely not... but clarification would be useful!

Comment: Very sorry - thx - I fixed notation - I did mean two feet long and about 6 inches deep.@Bamboo

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad tidings, but 6 inches deep means your trough or container isn't really suitable for roses - even miniature roses need 9-12 inches of soil beneath them. There is some information on growing roses in containers here, where it mentions deep pots as being suitable https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=278

The other factor to consider is winter - I think you are in USDA zone 6 or 7, but if you regularly get temperatures below 32degf day and night for longer than a week at a time, there is a high risk that the soil in the trough will freeze, and if that happens, roots will freeze too. The risk of that would mean relocating the trough to somewhere its less likely to freeze during winter.

If your winter temperatures do get that low, it might be better to use temporary planting for the summer and early fall, and replant again the following year. If you do want to check out roses, this site http://www.roguevalleyroses.com/content/zone-hardiness-information has a tose selector -you need to click on Advanced Search in the left hand menu and enter information. Even so, the available root depth is still an issue...

Comment: Right on the money Bamboo.  The first worry about planting in planters and pots is what the temperatures of the winter are like...second worry is what soil to use!

Comment: How were you able to figure out what zone they were in?

Comment: @stormy - checked their profile...some members put their location there, some don't... this one did, luckily...

Comment: Ah yes, I rarely do this bit.  Hey, have you ever seen a pure white flower on a gourd plant?

Comment: @stormy not personally, I hate squash so never have grown them, but I know calabash and ivy leaved gourd (Coccinia grandis) have white flowers...

Comment: Bamboo hates squash.  All kinds?  Summer and winter?  Poor thing!!  How about delectable winter squash soups?  Grins.  I hate brussel sprouts and okra!  I just found that squash do have white flowers that look like hibiscus.  Unbelievable.  I find, once again, I am on the wrong question.  Hey, it is 100 degrees F.  Here.  Has been for WEEKS. My brain is frying!

Comment: @stormy all kinds. I can just about bear baby courgettes and maybe sliced cucumber, but all the bigger ones are  either horribly watery and tasteless, or fibrous, yuk. The only thing I'd do with pumpkin soup is flush it down the sink ...and yea, this should have been under the bottle gourd question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81488/discussion-between-bamboo-and-stormy).

Answer (score 1):

Lewis, any rose can be planted in a planter.  6" is fine for roots but not so much for drainage.  You need your soil depth to be at least one foot, one and 1/2 feet for stability.  Holes in the bottom of the planter, critical.

You have to use just sterilized potting soil in your planter.  Critical.  The pot and pruning control the size of plants planted in a pot.

I am trying to find the rose group of floriferous shrub or floribundas...that are even better.  I'll edit this soon, got to find those roses fairly a newbie type. Haven't found the name I was looking for but 'groundcover' roses would be in this category as well as mini's.

Do not add compost to that sterilized potting soil.  Silly.  Potting soil needs no help for drainage and compost ain't sterilized.  Do not FEED like crazy either. Keep the fertilizer so that the Nitrogen is the lowest in percentage of the 3 macro chemicals. The third thing is 'bigger is better' for pots is wrong. I disagree with these three things in this article.[rose container gardening](https://www.heirloomroses.com/info/care/how-to/rose-container-gardening/)

[Sunsprinkles mini roses for planters](https://www.jacksonandperkins.com/sun-sprinkles-miniature-rose/p/v2033/?gclid=Cj0KCQjw77TbBRDtARIsAC4l83logsvZKhkF0G-koipumIY_F6o74_QQQPymYwwG_zFbnjIGIP3ScG8aApz_EALw_wcB&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=ppc_google_pla2&gdffi=341ebfce6bce4cc5b5f6be51f712e281&gdfms=4B5FAF639C7046FA9973C6F7E12530CF&ef_id=WLm5IQAAAGs3oBv9:20180811002118:s)

Comment: And the best time to buy plants, any plant sold in a nursery, is usually the fall.  The mark up goes markedly down as the season dwindles.  Sunsprinkles will continue to produce roses all season long.  Your roses will be much more full and bountiful next spring once they have a chance to acclimate to the new home.

Comment: Exactly! Very good and true answer!

Answer (score 0):

For pots [miniature](https://www.mygardenlife.com/plant-library/2531/rosa/hybrid) roses or pot roses are suitable. Usually best time to buy them is early in season (spring).

Comment: The best time being spring is helpful, but what are my options if I want them now? Is it hopeless, or are there steps I can take to still make it work now? @b.nota

Comment: I am afraid most roses are already blooming now or stopped blooming already (Summer, Northern hemisphere), so not very attractive to be sold now. Maybe a specialized rose nursery?

Comment: @LewisPringle Any reputable rose plants seller do have wide choice of roses all year around. I think your best bet would be online purchase.